# Stacked bar chart not updating correctly d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In [**this**](https://plnkr.co/edit/X7JYRLCKgBnasP86FRgQ?p=preview) stacked bar chart I've added a bisector and a custom `x.invert` function so you can read the values for each month:

The problem is that when I added this custom function the rectangles for team 2 & 3 are no longer updating the existing `rect` but re-draws the bars from the top left when you select a different category from the select dropdown and I have no idea why.

Removing all code relating to the `x.invert` function makes the bars update properly again, so it might have something to do with the x domain but I'm not sure.

Comment: Don't remove your key function, that's not a good practice.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado What problems can appear if we do not pass the function?

Comment: @MikhailShabrikov If you have just the enter selection, none. But if you have an update selection, depending on the data structure, a lot of problems can happen. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43890687/5768908

Comment: @MikhailShabrikov We just had an example today of things breaking because of the lack of a key function! Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48460303/5768908

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Pretty useful case, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a key function when binding the data is a very good practice in D3, which ensures object constancy. So, contrary to the suggestion in the <s>accepted</s> other answer, you should not remove it.

Instead of removing it, just **fix** the key function. The problem right now is that since the keys are...

```
["Team 1 CC", "Team 2 CC", "Team 3 CC"]
```

... for the selected dataset, this...

```
d.key.split(' ')[0]
```

.. will return `TEAM` for every group, and the keys obviously cannot be the same.

So, just do...

```
d.key.split(' ')[0] + d.key.split(' ')[1]
```

Or even just...

```
d.key.slice(0, -3)
```

... which will return: `TEAM 1`, `TEAM 2` and `TEAM 3`.

Here is your updated Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/XCvmDj9a3yF37dzDmA6d?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your mistake in this code:

```
let barGroups = g.selectAll("g.layer")
  .data(stacking, d=>d.key.split(' ')[0]);
```

You pass the second argument to `.data` method. According to [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_data):

> selection.data([data[, key]])
>
> ... A key function may be specified to control which
> datum is assigned to which element, replacing the default
> join-by-index, by computing a string identifier for each datum and
> element.

If you remove it your visualization will work [properly, checkmy fork of your plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/8Sr18sjLfV13QXZAfz9q?p=preview).